# Is this good design for Web User Control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am coming from an ASP.Net MVC background, so I like to design things well. I just started getting back into ASP.Net web forms again because my job requires it.

I have a user control which I would like to use to encapsulate an entire component (layout and code). Depending on certain settings for this control the layout may change, or I may call events, etc... Is it good practice to do something like this?

**<%# if(this.SomeProperty) .... %>** or **<%# if(this.something) this.runSomeMethod()) %>**

I have no clue what is good design regarding web user controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is rather subjective I'll give you my subjective opinion: Except in very few cases, I prefer to use codebehind to drive control and page logic. I don't mind "tag soup" per se, but I think it's far clearer to just do everything in proper code. When you have codebehind you also get the benefit of having a concrete class to refer to, which is useful in many ways, especially in larger projects.

That said, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: agreed. I prefer to use code behind for everything I possibly can. "Tag Soup" makes me mad and can get confusing and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with kprobst. Our team's best practice includes avoiding any sort of server side code in aspx files (except databinding calls). Any business or page logic can be more neatly organized on the code behind.

Tag soup is hard to avoid with Classic ASP, ColdFusion and PHP. It is easily avoidable with ASP.NET.